# How should one layout a UI similar to Any.do app iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitableview

How should one layout an Any.do app UI for iOS ?

I'm really confused on how Any.do made their UI in a table view controller or scroll view....
Or is it Collection reusable views?

Do you guys have any idea to layout that type of UI. I don't think storyboard would work very well in this case.

Thanks. I appreciate your help guys.

Links:
http://www.148apps.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Any.DO-White.jpg
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/any.do/id497328576

Comment: What's Any.do.app?  Perhaps post a screenshot with the particular UI elements you are interesting in imitating?

Comment: Bad question. There is a bazillion ways to implement something. Looks like a tableView with some Cell Resizing magic. But I don't know the app, and I don't want to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Today", "Tomorrow", "Next Week" views appear (from the way the app works) to be UITableView section headers. Tapping on the section header expands or collapses the rows in that section. Apple has a demo project, "Table View Animations and Gestures",  that shows how they do this.